# What does this engine weigh?

Tags: engine, weight

We have this old inline 6 engine on our property. We guess it is from a Chevy Panel Truck from 1963 (something like this: http://davidsclassiccars.com/chevrolet/69489-1963-chevrolet-panel-truck.html) I'm an average muscular guy, I can lift a bit but not move it at all.

We need to haul it away but it is hard to estimate the weight without a scale, to get the right equipment.

Is 700 lbs a good estimate?[image]

Comment: More like 400lbs

Comment: I'm not sure, either, but I think Moab is in the ballpark. I wouldn't expect it to be anymore than that. If you cannot find a way to take it all at once, consider breaking the engine down into components, which would be a LOT more manageable.

Comment: "*What does this engine weigh?*"  Is this like the game where you if you can guess the number of jelly beans in a jar you win a prize?  344 lbs An engine cherry picker will get it off the ground for you.

Comment: I'd guess more like 500 lbs. My aluminum v6 weighs 460 with all components (or so the internet claims), so I'm guessing that iron block would be more.

Comment: @AlaskaMan - If that is the actual weight (which it does sound about right), please post it as its own answer below and delete your comment.

Comment: This thread has weights ranging from 440 - 630 lbs for a Chevy inline 6.
http://67-72chevytrucks.com/vboard/showthread.php?t=495029

Comment: It depends some on the year.. Older engines have thicker walls, nothing you can see from the outside, To compete with the lighter aluminum engines ,iron foundries were able to significantly reduce section thicknesses and reduce weight. The only way to know is to weigh it.

Comment: I found out a bit more, just updated the year of the truck. A cherry picker alone won't do. It is hard to access the engine with a cherry picker. Will need to haul the thing to level ground first.

Comment: Just hook a chain to it and drag the thing. Should be plenty of points you could tie to on it. And I mean, use a vehicle to tow it. I don't think I'd be too afraid of damaging the engine :o)

Comment: According to this link it weighs 440lbs, Chevy L6 194-250 cu inch, accessories can had substantial weight which yours does not have.>>>>>https://www.gomog.com/allmorgan/engineweights2.html

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  Posting a guess as an answer is not really proper  here. Not to mention that there is no way to definitively answer "*What does this engine weigh?*" as we can not know what that thing weighs. If i win, when can expect my prize?

Comment: @mitchkman "*A cherry picker alone won't do*" Why do you think that? . Bolt a chain sling to both ends of the crankshaft, hook to cherry picker, and lift. Cherry pickers are made for the express purpose of removing engines from vehicles. Or make a tripod and hang a chain hoist from it. You can do it, i have faith in you.

Comment: Old Chevy V-8s of that era weigh 600-700 lbs... so 500-ish is about right. *You should definitely not be trying to lift it without leverage*.  That inline-6 is a treasure; I'd suggest hitting up old engine forums and see if anyone wants to haul it away for you. Meanwhile if you're going to manhandle it, put the valve cover back on to keep from plowing dirt into the engine innards.  It's only 6 screws, surely 1/4 or 5/16.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An online search lead to, 440 lbs if its a 250cid motor. Closer to 500lbs if it is a 292cid motor. The 292 is about 2 inches longer so it weighs more.

Comment: Don't forget to subtract the harmonic balancer and timing chain.